# Implementing HTTP/2 client using python 3.5 hyper library

Tags: python, http2, python-hyper

Im trying to implement my own HTTP/2 client using python3.5 hyper library. Everything seems to work fine until I request objects larger than 64Kb.

I've already set the `network_buffer_size` in larger values than the default which is actually 64K, even set the library code to set the network_buffer_size big enough so it could process the response but still the amount of data received from server is 64K no matter how big the file is.

```
conn = hyper.HTTP20Connection(SERVER, int(sys.argv[2]), True, window_manager=FlowControlManagerUs, enable_push=False, ssl_context=ssl_context)
conn.network_buffer_size = 256000
conn.connect()
```

And here's where I get the request:

```
resp = conn.get_response(strid)
data = resp.read()
```

I've implemented the FlowControlManager just setting initial_window_size to large value.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Just edited the question ! Thanks @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Flow-control in HTTP/2 is implemented via two type of flow control windows: one for the connection, and one for each stream, in the words of [RFC 7540, 5.2 Flow control](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5.2):

> A flow-control scheme ensures that streams on the same connection do
> not destructively interfere with each other.  Flow control is used for
> both individual streams and for the connection as a whole.

hyper allows to implement your own flow control policy by sub classing `hyper.http20.window.BaseFlowControlManager`. By setting `initial_window_size` to large value, you've set the **connection window** to a large value. The stream window however is left unchanged, and it turns out that the default value for the stream window *is* 64 kb, from section [5.2.1 Flow-Control Principles](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5.2.1):

> 4. The initial value for the flow-control window is 65,535 octets
>    for both new streams and the overall connection.

In order to increase the window for the stream, you'll have to also implement the `increase_window_size` method of the flow-control manager.